# Call interface by using variable name

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

I assign the interface name in variable, through that variable, i need to call interface i.e. in ChannelFactory class accept only interface.If I directly specify the interface as Test in the ChannelFactory, then it's working fine.

```
 string interfaceName = "Test";
 var factory = new ChannelFactory<**interfaceName**>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(*********));
```

Please suggest possible the way, how to typecast from string variable to interface.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot directly typecast from a string variable to an interface. You can however use reflection to create a generic type.

Be aware however, that the resulting factory will be of type object, so calling all interface methods on it will also have to be done trough reflection (or by using the [dynamic keyword)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

The following code will create the ChannelFactory trough reflection but as you can see the result is of type object, meaning you can't call channel methods directly on it.

```
string interfaceName = "StackOverflow.ITest";

Type f = typeof (ChannelFactory<>);
Type[] typeargs = {Type.GetType(interfaceName, true)};

Type constructed = f.MakeGenericType(typeargs);
object factory = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
```

Comment: Although by changing the last line to `var factory = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed) as ChannelFactory;` you retain some basic channel functionality in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **you can't do that!** 
Your code line

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<interfaceName>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(***));
```

may suggest that factory (of type `var`) is a *variant*, but it isn't. It is a variable and it is type safe, made by the compiler due to the generic call `new ChannelFactory<interfaceName>`. So you cannot specify a variable interface in the generic call there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass interfaceName as string in a generic constraint. You can do the below

```
string interfaceName = "Test";
Type myInterfaceType = Type.GetType(interfaceName);
var factoryType = typeof(ChannelFactory<>).MakeGenericType(myInterfaceType);
var factoryCtr = factoryType.GetConstructor(new []{ typeof(Binding), typeof(EndpointAddress)});
ChannelFactory factory = factoryCtr.Invoke(new object[]{ new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("")}) as ChannelFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from Fischermaen's answer, second, **you can't do that, either!**

The type argument list of a generic type (the type names in angle brackets; for example, "int" in `List<int>`) *are not variables*.  They are static compile-time tokens.  You could no more do this than what you seek to do:

```
string className = "FileInfo";
**className** theObject = new **className**("C:\\autoexec.bat");
```

Because C# is a statically-typed language, the types denoted by type-name tokens must be statically known at compile time.  Note that the reflection-based answers here leave you with a reference whose static type is a subtype of `ChannelFactory<TChannel>`, either the non-generic `ChannelFactory` or `object`.  You can't have a static compile-time reference to a type that will be known only at run time.